# How to Align Two UI Button Horizontally Aligned in A Xib Using Size Class and Auto Layout

Tags: ios, autolayout, size-classes

How to Align Two UI Button Horizontally Aligned in A Xib Using Size Class and Auto Layout. Two Button should keep its original height and width

[image: Button Should be aligned like this]

i would like to achieve this without code

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have to make their centerY constraints to 0 , give Gallery button a height and a width constraint and have a equal width and height constraints.

Comment: @SabricanOzan  if you don't mind can you pleas explain it little more ?

Comment: @SARATH just posted an answer below try that and give me feedback if somethings wrong :)

Comment: thank you @SabricanOzan. i will check and let u know :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First add gallery button:

- Height constaint
- Width constraint
- Leading space with superview
- Top space with superview

Then add camera button:

- Horizontal space with Gallery button
- Equal width with Gallery button
- Equal height with Gallery button
- CenterY with Gallery button

And it should be done.

Comment: Are you adding camera button programatically ? If thats the case you should check translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints property

Comment: When you set your constraints is there any constraint warnings in Interface Builedr or any break of a constraints when you open that screen in app ?

Comment: no not at all. im using UIScrollView in the View. warnings are there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89799/discussion-between-sabrican-ozan-and-sarath).

Comment: Can we use this same solution for dynamic sized UIButtons. ie. the button should increase or decrease its size according to its content view

Comment: You cannot use this solution for it but with a minor change you may. You should delete width constraint of gallery button and add a trailing space to superview to camera button. I haven't tried it but that should be it :)

Comment: In story Board that Center Y is not Showing ?

Answer (score 3):

Check this video, to set the constraints

[image]

You can check in the preview,
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Select both Buttons.

Add the following constraints show in image

[image]

This will add default height depend on Text Font.

[image]

So if you want to increase height then Select any one button and add extra height constraint. Update the frame.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just simple select Two Button and  Give horizontal and vertical spacing constraints and give Equal Width and Equal Height to Button.

Answer (score 0):

1. Connect your `Gallery` button to your main view's corner and set it using
2. Next, connect your `Camera` button to `Gallery` button and set `Horizontal Spacing`.
3. Inside your Storyboard's `Leading Alignment Contstraint`, set `Gallery.Trailing` as `First Item`, and `Camera.Leading` as `Second Item`. Set `Relation` to `Equal`.